# saving bitmap when a file already has that name

Tags: android

I'm currently downloading an image from the the web and converting it to a bitmap the problem is the image will always be called 1.jpg or 2.jpg. So my question is how can I save the file as say 1.jpg(2) or something similar if the image already exists on the sd card? is there an example of the code needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which platform are you using and tools?

Does that mean Andriod 2.0? My idea would be check if the file with that name already exists if it does use a different name. If the two images are really the same, there is no need to use a different name.

May be you want to clarify you needs a little more.

Comment: sorry to clarify the images are different it's just that the site I'm getting the images from only labels them as 1.jpg and 2.jpg these are updated daily. So say I save the images one day and the next day I try again how can I save those without overwriting yesterdays

Comment: I dont know what is your accepted format but I would use something like this 1_000.jpg, 1_001.jpg and again check if the filename exist, increment the counter by 1.

The format 1.jpg(1), 1.jpg(2) are supported only be operating system. Your code will not do it be default. You have to implement it yourself.